# If I reformat a partition will it invalidate all system restore points?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, formatting

I have to reformat (or perhaps re-partition) at least one (possibly 2) of the partitions on my computer. (I have only 1 physical hard drive in the computer).

The first partition (drive) I am reformatting contains only DATA. There are no programs installed on this partition.

The second partition (drive) is not the OS partition (not the drive with C:\Windows), but it does contain the "\Program Files (x86)" and "\Program Files" folders.

For the first drive, I have backed up all the data and I will reformat it. But, this will erase the "\System Volume Information" folder.

I don't believe that there is anything in the "system restore points" for this drive because there are no programs installed on this drive, but if there happens to be "something" in the "system restore points" for this drive, I don't mind loosing it because I have everything on the drive backed up.

What I don't know, is how will erasing (reformatting) the "\System Volume Information" folder on this drive (any one drive) effect the overall "system restore points" in general. In other  words, will the "system restore" process realize the information in the "\System Volume Information" folder on this drive has been deleted and then invalidate all "system restore points" on all partitions (drives) ?

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium x64.

Answer (score 2):

If you reformat the C partition, you will lose your restore points. This is the only partition where they are kept. If you want to preserve system status at certain times, I recommend you make occasional images. The free Macrium program is a good tool for that. Macrium is preferred over the Windows imaging because it has more function, is more flexible and more reliable.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I